# Polynomial Rewriting Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

*Note*. Please provide only a hint along with some explanation, but not the answer. I want to struggle with this problem. This is **not** homework.

> Show that for any number $c$, a polynomial $ P(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + \cdots b_n x^n$ can also be written as $P(x) = a_0  + a_1 (x - c) + a_2 ( x- c)^2 + a_3(x - c)^3\cdots a_n(x - c)^n$ where $a_0  = P(c)$.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: @BenjaLim: How will I do a proof by induction here?

Comment: Perhaps consider $P(x+c)$?

Comment: $= b_0 + b_1(x + c) + b_2(x + c)^2 +\cdots b_n(x + c)^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^r=(x-c+c)^r$$
$$=\sum_{0\le t\le r}\binom rt (x-c)^{r-t}c^t=(x-c)^r+\binom r1 (x-c)^{r-1}c+ \binom r2 (x-c)^{r-2}c^2+\cdots+\binom r{r-2} (x-c)^{2}c^{r-2}+\binom r{r-1} (x-c)^1c^{r-1}+c^r$$

Now put $r=0,1,2,3,\cdots,n-1,n$

Use the fact $\binom nr=0$ if $r>n$ or $r<0$

Comment: Ah, took me a while to understand this one. Thanks @lab :)

Comment: @DumbCow, I did not mention the Binomial Theorem by name,, as well-known.Anyway welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q(x) = P(x + c)$.  So $Q(x - c) = P(x)$.  What is $Q(0)$?  Can you show that $Q(x)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: How will that help? I mean, it is not really proven that both are equivalent...